# Tela preta ao executar um programa com Kivy

Tags: python, python-kivy

Não estou entendendo por que quando mando executar o seguinte código a tela aparece apenas preta. Alguém pode me dar um auxilio?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class Principal(App):
    def Build(self):
        self.img1 = Image(source= "images/Logo.jpg",size_hint= (.5, .3),pos_hint={"center_x":.5, "center_y":.9}),
        self.img2 = Image(source= "images/super.png",size_hint= (.99, .3), pos_hint={"center_x":.5, "center_y":.65}),
        lb1 = Label(text="Usuário: ",font_size= '15sp',size_hint= (None,None),pos_hint= {"center_x":.40, "center_y":.43},bold= True),
        lb2 = Label(text="Senha: ",size_hint= (None,None),font_size= "15sp",pos_hint={"center_x":.40, "center_y":.36},bold= True),
        lb3 = Label(text="Cadatre-se!",size_hint= (None, None),font_size= "8sp",pos_hint= {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.3},bold= True),
        lb4 = Label(text="Esqueceu sua senha?",size_hint= (None, None),font_size= "8sp",pos_hint= {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.32},bold= True)

        layoutVideo = FloatLayout()

        layoutVideo.add_widget(self.img1)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(self.img2)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(lb1)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(lb2)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(lb3)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(lb4)


        return layoutVideo

if __ name __ == "__ main __":

      Principal().run()
```

Comment: Talvez porque você criou o método `Build` e o Kivy espera `build`, com b minúsculo? Lembre-se que o Python é *case-sensitive*, então as duas palavras não são iguais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentado por Anderson o python é case-sensitive (diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas), e de acordo com a documentação do kivy o método `build()` está em caixa baixa (minúsculas). Para corrigir é preciso apenas substuir `Build()` por `build()`

Antes errado:

```
def Build(self):
        self.img1 = Image(source= "images/Logo.jpg",size_hint= (.5, .3),pos_hint={"center_x":.5, "center_y":.9}),
        self.img2 = Image(source= "images/super.png",size_hint= (.99, .3), pos_hint={"center_x":.5, "center_y":.65}),
        lb1 = Label(text="Usuário: ",font_size= '15sp',size_hint= (None,None),pos_hint= {"center_x":.40, "center_y":.43},bold= True),
        lb2 = Label(text="Senha: ",size_hint= (None,None),font_size= "15sp",pos_hint={"center_x":.40, "center_y":.36},bold= True),
        lb3 = Label(text="Cadatre-se!",size_hint= (None, None),font_size= "8sp",pos_hint= {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.3},bold= True),
        lb4 = Label(text="Esqueceu sua senha?",size_hint= (None, None),font_size= "8sp",pos_hint= {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.32},bold= True)

        layoutVideo = FloatLayout()

        layoutVideo.add_widget(self.img1)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(self.img2)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(lb1)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(lb2)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(lb3)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(lb4)


        return layoutVideo
```

Correto, trocando `Build()` por `build()`:

```
def build(self):
        self.img1 = Image(source= "images/Logo.jpg",size_hint= (.5, .3),pos_hint={"center_x":.5, "center_y":.9}),
        self.img2 = Image(source= "images/super.png",size_hint= (.99, .3), pos_hint={"center_x":.5, "center_y":.65}),
        lb1 = Label(text="Usuário: ",font_size= '15sp',size_hint= (None,None),pos_hint= {"center_x":.40, "center_y":.43},bold= True),
        lb2 = Label(text="Senha: ",size_hint= (None,None),font_size= "15sp",pos_hint={"center_x":.40, "center_y":.36},bold= True),
        lb3 = Label(text="Cadatre-se!",size_hint= (None, None),font_size= "8sp",pos_hint= {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.3},bold= True),
        lb4 = Label(text="Esqueceu sua senha?",size_hint= (None, None),font_size= "8sp",pos_hint= {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.32},bold= True)

        layoutVideo = FloatLayout()

        layoutVideo.add_widget(self.img1)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(self.img2)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(lb1)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(lb2)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(lb3)
        layoutVideo.add_widget(lb4)


        return layoutVideo
```

Tem outros erros no seu codigo:

Erro 1):

`if __ name __ == "__ main __":
      Principal().run()`

Estão com espaços entre `__` e `name` antes e depois, o mesmo ocorre em `__ main __`. O correto seria sem os espaços ficando assim:

`if __name__ == "__main__":
      Principal().run()`

Erro 2):
No método `build()` no fim de cada linha tem uma vírgula, fazendo com que seja atribuído uma tupla para a variável contendo o objeto e None, `(<kivy.uix.label.Label object at 0x7ff7c5ae6660>,None)`.

O correto:

```
def build(self):
        lb1 = Label(text="Usuário: ",font_size= '15sp',size_hint= (None,None),pos_hint= {"center_x":.40, "center_y":.43},bold= True)
        lb2 = Label(text="Senha: ",size_hint= (None,None),font_size= "15sp",pos_hint={"center_x":.40, "center_y":.36},bold= True)
        lb3 = Label(text="Cadatre-se!",size_hint= (None, None),font_size= "8sp",pos_hint= {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.3},bold= True)
        lb4 = Label(text="Esqueceu sua senha?",size_hint= (None, None),font_size= "8sp",pos_hint= {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.32},bold= True)
# o restante do codigo...
```

> Dica: dê preferência para criar os layouts em um arquivo `.kv` separado, deixe as classes para criar as "regras de negócio".

Comment: Curiosidade: você executou o código para saber se era somente esse o problema mesmo?

Comment: Sim, execeto os espaços em `__ name __ `  e `__ main __`que creio que deva ter sido erro durante a edição da pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado :D É que eu iria testar aqui, mas acabei não conseguindo tempo. Quanto aos espaços, sim, acho interessante adicionar na resposta. Podemos achar que foi apenas descuido, mas pode ser que não. Não custa deixar claro que está errado :D

Comment: Constavam na versão original também ^^

Comment: Moscada minha :# , tinham mesmo, editando a resposta